# Chrome extension: How to block and revise the content of request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm doing a extension to intercept the POST request to an url then change the content of the request. But I'm not familiar with JavaScript.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {     
    if (details.method == "POST") {
        return { cancel: true }; 
    }
  },
  {urls: ["*://www.google.com/*"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

I got some problems with this:

1. How to ignore the request if it is not post?
2. How should I resend the request?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: First, **why** are you trying to redirect POSTs? To stop people from sending you malicious files? Can't you just use validation on your server?

Comment: I'm trying to encrypt the password before posting. It is an experiment.